# Vias under SSOP IC, is this a problem?

Tags: pcb

I am trying to route connection on a board. However much I try there is always a via dropped below the IC. It is an SSOP package. IS this okay or is it an issue?

[image]

Comment: This is normal on professionally fabricated boards, subject to the constraints given in answers.  However, if you wanted to make the board yourself without plated through holes, it's all but unworkable, as whatever you run through the via holes to connect the layers would prevent the IC from seating properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by "below" you mean under the IC body, then this is OK (assuming that the package does not have a heat sink pad on the bottom surface). However, it looks like some of your traces are very, very close to the via rings.

Comment: I ran a drc and it didnt show me any errors so I assumed that its not an issue

Comment: Maybe not a DRC issue but your board yield may be affected, I'd recommend moving these if at all possible.

Comment: Running a DRC with the incorrect clearances set can lead you to believe it is ok - check those distances and check the DRC clearance settings - it looks less than 0.1mm to me.

Comment: All the clearances in the clearance settings are 8mil and they said its okay. Also what exactly is close? THe blue is the bottom layer and I see 2 red are placed quite far.

Comment: Via's are holes and the tollerance for holes is worse than the tollerance for track to tracks and pads. It's best to ask the Fab by giving them an example like those shown. However, if there is nothing else stopping them from being moved I would move them. Because the effort required is so small compared to the pain of shorts under an IC later...

Comment: I would really like to move them(vias) but there are other components that are immediately outside which prevent me from doing so. I am still unclear as to what exactly is too close. Could someone please clarify this for me?

Comment: Turn off all of the layers except Top and Vias. Look for the smallest spacing between objects. If that's greater than 8mil and your board vendor allows traces that close to vias then you are fine. Repeat for Bottom and Vias. As s3c said, using the minimum spacing allowed by the board house may give a lower yield than if you increased the minimum widths and spaces by 10% or 20%.

Comment: Also make sure that the IC can have traces routed there; some analog ICs are sensitive to external signals in some places.

Comment: Some ICs want or suggest a solid ground plane underneath, some do not. What they mean by move the vias they mean away from the pin layout. @DeveloperAndroid the top three are too close and could result in a short while soldering, with the middle two being really hard to check. The bottom two are a good distance away.

Comment: @Spoon - vias contain holes, but the clearance in question is between copper features (the via ring and traces) produced in the same process.  The hole location tolerance instead influences the minimum thickness of the via ring, which seems reasonable here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton . yes your right. Although I have seen some poor accuracy on cheap boards that would have been a problem if the drift had been in the wrong direction, they might have worked ok but they looked horrible... it was about 18 years ago... now i'm feeling old

Answer (score 7):

You can place via's anywhere you want however:

If this is a professional made board with plating inside via holes I would recommend 'tenting' these via's. This means that the soldermask is covered over the via so the metal is not exposed. If you don't tent these via's and they are close to solder pins, there is a very big chance solder will stick to this via. This 'short' is really tricky to remove and can take multiple resolder attempts (and a lot of heat/flux/good solder wick) of those pins to remove.
Whilst trying to remove the short, you can easily bend of break of a fragile SSOP pin, which is really frustrating I can tell you. ;)

If in doubt: place via's a fair distance (like half to 1 via size) away from the solder pins.

If this is a DIY board, then chances are you create via's by soldering a piece of metal wire on both sides of the board. In that case you usually have a solder joint sticking out under the IC, which means you can't mount the IC flat anymore. Unless you are really careful at trimming down the via solder joint down.

Comment: I plan to give it to a Fab but the components may be soldered by me with the help of a stencil